# angularjs assigning bind variables to html tag properties

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am going through the [Angularjs tuts and docs given in the official angularjs website.](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04)

Here we add a selectbox for ordering, like this

```
  <select ng-model="orderProp">
   <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
   <option value="age">Newest</option>
  </select>
```

and in the controller, we assign `$scope.orderProp = "age"` This works fine and 'Newest' will be the default select option.

Then I tried putting the order items to a model and populate the selectbox using ng-repeat like this.

```
  <select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option ng-repeat="orderby in orderProperties" value="{{orderby.criteria}}">{{orderby.property}}</option>
  </select>
```

where:

**orderProp** model is :

```
function PhoneListCtrl($scope){

    $(document).ready($scope.orderProp = "age");

        $scope.orderProperties = [
            {"property":"Alphabetical","criteria":"name"},
            {"property":"Newest","criteria":"age"}
        ];
}
```

In dom I can see the `value="name"` and `value="age"`. But this time the default value is not set as "Newest". I don't understand why the hardcoded `value="age"` is working, while `value="{{orderby.criteria}}"` is not. Can anyone please guide me through.

Comment: I've found, that the value is getting set during `$scope.orderProp = "age"` and sorting is getting triggered. But the selectbox `<select ng-model="orderProp">` is still empty. 
I am assuming it might be due something like assigning value before page load or something like that and might not be related to angularjs.

Comment: You should give a look [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select). It's explained how to use `select`. And you don't need `$(document).ready(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `select` in the wrong way:

```
<select ng-model="orderProp" 
    ng-options="orderby.criteria as orderby.property for orderby in orderProperties">
</select>
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`ng-option`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect) to populate the select.